# Getting the modifications of other people as pushable commits in git

Tags: git

I am facing a quite strange problem here as when I do a git pull, the files retrieved are seen by git as pushable changes

I think that began to happen after there was a conflict, which was then resolved
After that I kept on seeing commits waiting to be pushed in my pushable commits list

I use smartgit as GUI on windows 7, but the repo is on a unix machine

Comment: What is a "pushable commit list"? Is that something specific to smartgit?

Comment: Does this pushable commit list grow over time?

Comment: in smartgit, a "pushable commit list" is a list of local commits that have not been pushed to a remote repository

That makes my problem even more strange as these "pushable commits" were not made by me but by my co-workers !

Comment: Maybe your co-workers pushed their commits in `dev` branch, but you pulled & merged them to `master` branch..so these commits are still pushable to remote master branch. Just a personal guess. :p

Comment: @AlexandrPriymak yes, the list grows over time, with new commits from my co-workers

Comment: @Kjuly thanks for tipping it out, i'll check if it applies in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seemed to only be a bug in the gui